# How do you delete \n from a line?

Tags: string, python-2.7

I am reading lines from a file and putting them into a list. However, when I read the lines, they read in with a newline (`\n`). I have tried to remove it with `str.strip()`, `str.rstrip()`, `str.strip("\n")`, `str.rstrip("\n")`, `str.strip("\\n")`, and `str.rstrip("\\n")`, but

**none of them have done what I want them to.**

Here is the code.

```
lines=[]
with open(v) as x:
    for line in x:
        if "\n" in line:
            lines.append(line)
for line in lines:
    line.strip()
    if '\n' in line:
        print "I'm a stupid computer."
print lines
```

This yields precisely this output.

```
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    I'm a stupid computer.
    ['6\n', '1 2\n', '2 3\n', '3 1\n', '10 11\n', '100 10\n', '11 100\n', '1 100\n', '2     3\n', '3 2\n']
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String objects are **immutable** in Python. `line.strip()` doesn't change `line`; it returns a stripped **copy**. Use `line = line.strip()` instead (or better yet for your example, just append the stripped version to the list in the first place:

```
if "\n" in line:
    lines.append(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 2):

line.strip() creates a copy of the line without the leading/trailing whitespace. You are not doing anything with the copy, you need to assign it back to the line. You want:

`line = line.strip()`

You could also just use:

```
with open(v) as fin:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fin.readlines()]
```

You probably don't want want to only add the lines that contain a newline. Maybe what you do want is to omit those lines that don't contain anything else:

```
with open(v) as fin:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in fin.readlines() if line.strip()]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the output of `strip()` back to the variable:

`line = line.strip()`

Answer (score 1):

\n is one character, you can slice it.

```
line = line[0:len(line)-1]
```

or per @Henry's comment,

```
line[:-1]
```

Comment: Or `line = line[:-1]`. This doesn't really get at the heart of the problem, though, which is that the OP doesn't understand what the `strip()` method does.

Comment: I like this solution as well, but I have picked Henry's solution simply because it explained the part I was missing. This is good to know for the future, however. Thank you.